# Issues with Python ctypes '_as_parameter_' and 'from_param' on OS X

Tags: python, c, macos, ctypes, ffi

**tl;dr** The `_as_parameter_` and `from_param` mechanisms described in Python's `ctypes` documentation don't seem to be working correctly in OS X. Problem with our code or with `ctypes`?

---

**A little context**

The [GenomeTools library](https://github.com/genometools/genometools/) includes an extensive C API as well as a small set of Python bindings implemented with `ctypes`. I use the C API quite a bit, but I'm interested in using and contributing to the project's Python code. The C code is in `src/` and the Python bindings are implemented in `gtpython/`.

I wrote a dummy script to test things out.

```
from gt import *
print "DEBUG a"
ingff3 = GFF3InStream("testdata/Scaffold_102.gff3")
print "DEBUG b"
outgff3 = GFF3OutStream(ingff3)
print "DEBUG c"
outgff3.pull()
print "DEBUG d"
```

**The problem**

Ignoring the library-specific details, the [`GFF3InStream`](https://github.com/genometools/genometools/blob/2e9fbdc5c085190b127884616a05dba279ea562c/gtpython/gt/extended/gff3_in_stream.py) and [`GFF3OutStream`](https://github.com/genometools/genometools/blob/2e9fbdc5c085190b127884616a05dba279ea562c/gtpython/gt/extended/gff3_out_stream.py) classes are Python wrappers for C object types. The `GFF3OutStream` constructor calls the constructor `gt_gff3_out_stream_new` from the C library. The first argument to that C function is expected to be a pointer to a C object. The Python code that calls the function provides a Python object as the parameter, but because the object has the `_as_parameter_` attribute set and the `from_param` method defined, the value passed to the C code is actually the pointer the Python object encapsulates, not a pointer to the Python object itself.

That's the idea at least, and that's how it works on Linux. But on Mac OS X, I'm getting all kinds of segfaults since these mechanisms don't seem to be working. Only if I explicitly change the constructor from this...

```
class GFF3OutStream(GenomeStream):
    def __init__(self, genome_stream):
        self.gs = gtlib.gt_gff3_out_stream_new(genome_stream, None)
        self._as_parameter_ = self.gs
```

...to this...

```
class GFF3OutStream(GenomeStream):
    def __init__(self, genome_stream):
        self.gs = gtlib.gt_gff3_out_stream_new(genome_stream.gs, None)
        self._as_parameter_ = self.gs
```

...do I observe the correct behavior for my little dummy script on OS X.

Are the `_as_parameter_` and `from_param` mechanisms really not available on Mac OS X? Is this a known issue with Python's `ctypes`? Or is there something wrong with the GenomeTools code?

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the response. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getfunc` of `c_void_p` returns the pointer value as an integer. The default conversion for an integer argument is a C `int`, which truncates a 64-bit pointer value.

There are at least two ways to deal with this. Either wrap the integer result in `c_void_p`.

```
class GFF3OutStream(GenomeStream):
    def __init__(self, genome_stream):
        self.gs = c_void_p(gtlib.gt_gff3_out_stream_new(genome_stream, None))
        self._as_parameter_ = self.gs
```

Or set `restype` to a subclass of `c_void_p`, which skips calling the `getfunc`.

```
class my_void_p(c_void_p):
    pass

gtlib.gt_gff3_out_stream_new.restype = my_void_p

class GFF3OutStream(GenomeStream):
    def __init__(self, genome_stream):
        self.gs = gtlib.gt_gff3_out_stream_new(genome_stream, None)
        self._as_parameter_ = self.gs # my_void_p instance
```

---

2.7.8 ctypes source links:

- [`P_get`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1580)
- [`ConvParam`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l613)
- [`GetResult`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l903)